# Gated builds of TFS 2015 for GIT

Tags: git, tfs

Can any one enlighten me how TFS gated builds are working with GIT source control?
Are they check and build by commits or by pull request or even differently?

Answer (score 2):

Gated builds aren't supported for Git, for a really simple reason: Git is a distributed version control system. The entire idea behind a gated check-in is that you validate the code is building before it's committed, but you can't do that in a DVCS, since the code has to be committed before it can be pushed.

TFS 2015 introduces [Branch Policies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/code/git/branch-policies?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) alongside Pull Requests, so you can enable a branch policy for a given branch that restricts merges until certain criteria have been met (code reviews, builds, and work item links). When a branch policy is enabled, all merges to that branch will have to come in the form of a pull request, so you can "gate" your merges into that branch.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately， gated build are not working for Git.

> You can use most TFBuild capabilities to build one team project at a
>   time, and one or more repositories at a time. **Gated check-in builds
>   aren’t available yet.** Symbols can be published, but they are not
>   indexed yet.
>
> Source from MSDN: [Use Version Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/code/overview)

Comment: If you want to support the idea of having gated builds in the product, please vote on this User Voice item: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519/suggestions/8775376

Comment: Gated check-ins aren't available for **TFVC** at the moment. Git has branch policies and pull requests, which are a more robust alternative. IMO there is no need for the build system to support gated check-in for Git.